Dream Catchers as a Native Noahide
I am Native, and I want to buy a dream catcher, but I'm afraid it'll be bad to have as a noahide. I don't believe it has mythical or magical stuff I just think it's pretty to have in my home. Should I purchase one or simply not?...

Does this answer your question? Are "dream catchers" considered to be avodah zarah?

@shmosel that answer may be helpful for a Jew... however Noahides (to my recollection) are not warned against nihush. So the analysis would be different here.

Nice to have you here Nee. We hope you stick around and continue to learn with us. You may notice in the sidebar it states: "Like any library, Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but does not offer personalized, professional advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your rabbi." Given that this is a request for a personal situation rather than a generic request for knowledge on the topic, it is likely that your question will be closed. You can always edit the question in order to bring it in line with site policy. All the best.

Why was this question closed it was perfectly valid??

@CuriousYid It says why it's closed. Not all valid questions are on-topic here.

So if the question gets rephrased without the word "I" it would be a valid question?

Yeah the question is simply “are dreamcatchers allowed for noahides?” Literally nothing wrong with that

@CuriousYid from the help center: "Questions that appear to be requests for personal practical advice will be either edited to more general wording or closed" As currently worded, the question appears to be soliciting personalized practical advice. The question can certainly be edited in order to brought in line with standing policy.
